# Repeater control paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, paging

I've got a repeater control containing comments. I'm about to implement ajax paging to it. I was opting to use the updatepanel (conditionally) for this thing, but I guess it's going to get kinda slow in production environment (Each time about 20 rows will be visible).

Do you guys have any other ideas on how to do this? I want to keep the repeater control since it contains other controls as well so I can't use a js (templates)/json approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the paging inside a stored procedure. You can use a common table expression with the ROW_NUMBER() function to limit your results to 20 rows. Using an Update Panel might be a little slower than just passing JSON data asynchronously but it plays well with the Repeater control.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that and use the repeater control. I saw u can make it quite speedy when disabling viewstate. And it will be the only updatepanel in the page so guess it will be ok yeah. Thanks and Take care

Comment: Here is a quick example of the paging using Transact-SQL:

;WITH Contacts_CTE AS
(
   SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LastName) AS RowNum
   FROM Contacts
)

SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM Contacts C INNER JOIN Contacts_CTE CTE ON C.Id = CTE.Id WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 20

You can easily create parameters to change the hardcoded 1 and 20 to use a PageIndex and PageCount variables.

Comment: Thanks man, got it to work. It has become pretty fast afterall.